# User Experience With MoSync

Tags: appcelerator

Has anyone tried using MoSync lately? Apparently they are dropping the "beta" title soon and will be officially launching in a few weeks. How do they compare to say Appcelerator?

Answer (score 1):

You should try the new new version,

http://www.mosync.com/documentation/manualpages/whats-new-mosync-26-pyramid

I especially love the HTML integration, the ability to create and call native code, it both directions, cool :) I'm really excited about the potential of HTML UI.

Tony

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator works by building you an application that contains a WebKit and JavaScript engine that runs your application.  This makes the build's slightly bigger.

MoSync can target more platforms than AppCelerator because it's designed to be able to output to any target platform.